# vbscript SendKey

Tags: vbscript, sendkeys

I have a process I need to run which can only be run by shortcut keys which are CTRL+ALT+RIGHT SHIFT

To make it easier for users I would like to create a desktop shortcut to click on to run this shortcut.

The way I thought this could be done is by vbs script sendkey.

Am I right in my research to say that right shift key can not be specified?

I know there is ^% for CTRL and ALT and + for generic shift but that does not work for right shift.

Is there a way for me to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

It has a very robust, proven "sendkey" functionality, including the ability to send right shift.

Your script would simply be:

```
SendInput,^!{RSHIFT}
```

Furthermore, it comes with a utility that will compile the script into a .exe, which is what you'd want to use on the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

I use my own open source software "sendkeys v0.0.1" for this. You can compile it as a C# console application in Visual Studio 2013.

Source: [Sendkey v0.0.1](http://pastebin.com/raw/yWUTjUif)

Then use it in a command window like this:

```
 Sendkey CONTROL down
 Sendkey MENU down
 Sendkey RSHIFT down
 Sendkey CONTROL up
 Sendkey MENU up
 Sendkey RSHIFT up
```

Or in vbscript using the .Exec() method.

(N.B. command window is Microsoft slang for 'terminal' or 'console')